# Best way to show image previews before upload in rails & carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, upload, carrierwave, preview

I've been using rails for past few days and wanted to know what is best way to show image previews before upload in rails & carrierwave.

I came across a few options like using plupload or jquery file upload or using uploadify.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you only need image preview in a form before upload, you (as me) will see that JQuery Upload plugin is just too much complex and not so easy to run properly (I was able to see the preview, but then I couldn't upload the picture).

http://saravani.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/preview-of-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded/

It's simple and fast to code.

I put the code here just in case the source dies:

Script:

```
    <!-- Assume jQuery is loaded -->
    <script>
      function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#img_prev')
              .attr('src', e.target.result)
              .width(150)
              .height(200);
          };

          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
      }
    </script>
```

In the HTML:

```
    <!--[if IE]>
      <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
      <img id="img_prev" src="#" alt="your image" />
    </body>
```

Comment: I think it's using some HTML5 functionality, that's probably the cause.

Comment: IE do not have FileReader class

Comment: @Puce for multiple images [MDN has a good example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL). This MDN page also shows browser compatibility

Answer (score 5):

You can use the plugin [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) which it's a full solution, but if you need something less robust, you can also try using [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader) directly, like [this](http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload), so you can customize the functionality to whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documents `image_cache` is showing what you are uploading.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :image_cache %>
```

Comment: which document? any reference available?

Comment: If you provide any reference to the document, it will be better.

Comment: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#making-uploads-work-across-form-redisplays

Comment: This functionality is for redisplaying across submissions, not for previewing.

Comment: I used this functionality, but if a user goes to his profile to change say his last name for example, it requires him to upload again the picture, althought it was already loaded in a previous session, and the picture is visible. NOt sure how to handle.