# How to display unsaved images in create page rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, carrierwave

I am building a job app with rails. In my job 'new' page, I have a preview functionality where a user can click on the 'preview' button to have a look at how the job posting would look like. In creating the job, the user would need to upload a company logo. I would like to find a way of previewing the company logo on the create.html.erb. I am using Carrierwave.

I have checked out solutions like [rails preview image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485967/best-way-to-show-image-previews-before-upload-in-rails-carrierwave) but that seems to work on only new.html.erb. My aim is to display the preview in create.html.erb

In my new.html.erb, i have

```
<%= f.input :unregistered_company_logo, :label => "Company Logo" %>
<%= f.input :unregistered_company_logo_cache, as: :hidden %>

<%= f.button :submit , name: "previewButt", value: "Preview", formtarget:"_blank", data: { disable_with: false }%>
```

In the create.html.erb, I have

```
<%= image_tag @job.unregistered_company_logo, class: "show-logo" %>
```

In the create action, i have

```
 def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)
      if params[:previewButt] == "Preview"
        flash[:alert] = "This is a PREVIEW of your job posting. Go back to the previous tab to Post the job or make edits."
        render :create
      elsif
        params[:createButt] == "Post Job"
        @job.save
        flash[:notice] = "Success!"
        redirect_to @job
      else
        render :new
      end
  end
```

How do i preview the uploaded logo in create.html.erb page so the user can see how exactly it would look like on show.html.erb. As i mentioned, the solutions that i have seen online seem to only display the preview on new.html.erb.

Comment: Do you mean you want to preview the image before it is uploaded?

Comment: yes, but i want to preview it in create.html.erb instead of new.html.erb. In the create.html.erb, i essentially have the same code as my show.html.erb @BenKelly